# Angularjs directive with replace true needs to return value

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, angularjs

I have a situation in which I need to use angularjs to modify a form by taking a single text field and turn it into a dropdown and another textfield.  The code behind the page will be looking for the original text field, so I need to feed the data back to the original text field.

Changing the original form would be difficult.  I cannot touch the code behind it.  As far as the back end is concerned, this needs to be the same form.

I'm trying to do this by attaching the following angularjs directive to the original text field.  As far as it appears, everything seems to be working just fine ... right up until I submit the form.  Once the form is submitted, the original text field becomes empty again.

How do I properly return the data to the original field that is being replaced?

```
function debug(x){ try { console.log(x); } catch (x) {} }

angular.module('app',['ngCookies','ngResource','ui'])
.directive('opsDirectChoice', function(){
    return {
        'restrict'    :    'A',
        'require'     :    'ngModel',
        'scope'       :    true,
        'template'    :    '<span>' + 
                            '<select style="font-size:11px" ng-model="choose_phoneLoc">' + 
                                '<option value="NY">New York</option>' + 
                                '<option value="SF">San Francisco</option>' + 
                            '</select>' + 
                            '<input type="text" ng-model="number_phoneLoc" value="">' +
                            '</span>',
        'replace'    :    true,
        'link'        :    function($scope, elem, attrs, ctrl){    
            phoneFilter = function(phoneIn){
                var phoneOut = phoneIn.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '');

                if( phoneOut.length > 7 ){
                    phoneOut = phoneOut.substring(0,3) + '-' + phoneOut.substring(3,6) + '-' + phoneOut.substring(6,10);
                }else if( phoneOut.length > 3 ){
                    phoneOut = phoneOut.substring(0,3) + '-' + phoneOut.substring(3,7);
                }

                return phoneOut;
            };

            /*
            $scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (newValue, oldValue) {
                debug(' ng Model is changed: ' + oldValue + ' => ' + newValue);
                if( newValue != oldValue ){
                    if( newValue.substring(0, 1) == 'D' ){
                        $scope.choose_phoneLoc = 'D';
                    }else{
                        $scope.choose_phoneLoc = 'OPS';
                    }

                    debug('ngmodel:  setting number_phoneLoc to phoneFilter(newValue): ' + phoneFilter(newValue));

                    $scope.number_phoneLoc = phoneFilter(newValue);
                }
            });
            */

            $scope.$watch('choose_phoneLoc', function(newValue, oldValue){
                if( newValue != oldValue ){
                    if( newValue ){
                        setViewValue();
                    }
                }
            });

            $scope.$watch('number_phoneLoc', function(newValue, oldValue){
                if( newValue != oldValue ){
                    $scope.number_phoneLoc = $scope.choose_phoneLoc + '\t' + phoneFilter(newValue);

                    setViewValue();
                }
            });

            function setViewValue(){
                var temp = phoneFilter($scope.number_phoneLoc);

                debug('Setting OPS to: ' + $scope.choose_phoneLoc + ' ' + temp);

                //  attrs.ngModel = $scope.choose_phoneLoc + '\t' + temp;
                ctrl.$setViewValue($scope.choose_phoneLoc + '\t' + temp );
                // ctrl.$render();
            }

            $scope.choose_phoneLoc = 'NY';
            $scope.number_phoneLoc = phoneFilter(attrs.ngModel);

        }
    };
})
```

Comment: why not use ng-switch or ng-show/hide then evaluate which needs to be shown using the pages controller - it would be a lot less work than trying to mess with the DOM replacing then reversing the replacement - that is kind of what the switch and show/hide are for

Comment: @Mark-Sullivan if you can show me how to do that without having direct access to the original form I'd sure appreciate it.

Comment: are you saying you don't have access to the original html file? my question then would be how are you getting your directive on the page?

Comment: @Mark-Sullivan Through a customization field that allows extra javascript to be added to the page, on document ready I'm adding all the angular-js code and then bootstrapping it.

Comment: can you post the html form that you are trying to modify?

Comment: @Mark-Sullivan Not really.  Wish I could.  It's of exceptionally long size and dynamically built, has nested tables inside nested tables inside nested tables (repeat x5), and really is entirely overdesigned for being more or less a very basic html form with some very mild 'require this field to be filled in' javascript mixed in.